# Element manipulation with CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, nav-pills

I'm doing some manipulation, presumably with jQuery, which is a lot like a previously asked question here:
[Hide and show divID with Javascript - Hide when new title is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104100/hide-and-show-divid-with-javascript-hide-when-new-title-is-opened/)

I have made a jsfiddle of my problem. I am working on some pills/tabs, where each pill is split into three parts, each containing a possibility to "Read more", which is where the show/hide comes into play. My jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwb99gw1/6/

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Pills</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <a class="" href="#a">Read more</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <a href="#b">Read more</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <h3>Something else</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <a href="#c">Read more</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="a">Lorem ipsum (A)</div>
        <div id="b">Lorem ipsum (B)</div>
        <div id="c">Lorem ipsum (C)</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, I have made a purely CSS-based solution, however it is not capable of handling UX. I would like "Read more" to switch to "Hide text", once clicked, and of course if clicked in that state, then hide the text. Ideally, switching pill/tab should also hide elements.

A few things are different in my problem, compared to the question I linked in the beginning. The elements are not enclosed by each other, so I don't think the "this" keyword will work, at least not exactly how the previous question handled it.

How would you go about fixing this? There must be a smarter work-around than ID by ID jQuery handling.

Comment: Here is a good place to use `$(elem).data`. You can store information in them just like attributes, instead, they are hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `.display-box` to your `.container`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container display-box">
    ...
        <a data-target="#a">Read more</a>
        <a data-target="#b">Read more</a>
        <a data-target="#c">Read more</a>
    ...
        <div id="a" class="box">Lorem ipsum (A)</div>
        <div id="b" class="box">Lorem ipsum (B)</div>
        <div id="c" class="box">Lorem ipsum (C)</div>
    ...
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".display-box").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("[data-target]").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $($this.data("visible")).hide();
            $("[data-target='"+$this.data("visible")+"']").text("Read more");
            if ($this.data("visible") !== $(this).data("target")) {
                $this.data("visible", $(this).data("target"));
                $(this).text("Hide text");
                $($this.data("visible")).show();
            } else {
                $this.data("visible", "")
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display:none;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwb99gw1/11/

### Explaination

Basically, this iterates for every `.displaybox` and find every element that has an attribute `data-target` then add a click event listener for each of them.

It hides the element specified in the data `data-visible` for `.display-box` but this data is hidden from inspector. It then grabs the value of `data-target` from clicked links and store it back in `data-visible`. Then it shows the element specified in the `data-visible` which is target of the clicked link.

Comment: That worked brilliantly! Thanks a lot for the in-depth answer and explanation.

Comment: @TobiasKrøgholt You're welcome. You should use more `.data()` for future similar problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a class to reference the clicked element, we shall have to use some sort of parent relation. The following method may prove **very useful when we don't have control over the DOM being generated**, So it can be done as follows ...

```
hideall = function(){
 jQuery("#home p ").next("a").each(function(e){ // accessing all the pairs of readmore elements and their respective companion elements
    readmore2 = jQuery(this).attr('href'); // get the readmoreid
    id2 = readmore2.substr(1); // extract the id
    jQuery("#"+id2).hide();
 });
}
jQuery("#home p ").next("a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault; // prevent the <a> tag from navigating
  readmore = jQuery(this).attr('href'); // get the readmoreid
  id = readmore.substr(1); // extract the id
  hideall();
  jQuery("#"+id).show();
});

jQuery(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   hideall();
});
```

Even if this solution works, this is not the right way to do it, I'd suggest you to use classes for a much efficient and better code.

Comment: Appreciate you getting back to me :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wow I am way late on the answer, but I worked on it so I'll post anyways.

```
$(function(){    
$(".a").click(function () {
$(".p").toggle();
$(this).text(function(i, text){
return text === "Read more" ? "Hide text" : "Read more";
}) 
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwb99gw1/6/)